# Active Directory Domain Controller Configuration with one internet connection & one lan card

Tags: local-area-network

I have a confusion since long time.

"I have configured AD on my win server 2008 R2 system  and i have one internet connection with only single lan card. thing is that while i am assigning Static IP address, internet is not coming.
i.e., i am not able to access the internet.

i need solution for ; how can i configure my Domain Controller with single lan card and single internet connection"

hope you understood....

Answer (score 3):

1. Plug the network network cable into the network card on the DC. It's the one that looks like an oversized phone cable.
2. In the network adapter properties in Windows, assign a valid IP address for your network.
3. Assign a valid subnet mask in the same window.
4. Assign a valid gateway in that window.
5. Assign a valid DNS server in the same window. If this is your only DC in the domain, use 127.0.0.1